# Where I'm supposed to ask so called opinion based question?

Tags: discussion

I want to develop a web application and I want to ask what's best approach for storing some big amount of data with fairly big enough users. I tried database, stackoverflow, programmers, codereview... All I got was downvotes. All I was told is "opinion-based", "opinion-based" and guess what else? Opinion based.

But I want to know the answer! I want to know what system should I really use to not have performance problem later, some people have experience with DynamoDB, some with NoSQL, some with MySQL, I want them to tell me what each of these can handle and what they can't and pros and cons of them. I did my research but hearing from an experienced actual user of these systems is something better. So what should I do in this situation ?

P.S. I think this question is also opinion based as some people would say I'm looking for opinions of meta users about my situation.

P.S.S. I re-updated and re-asked my question, so far not closed "yet":
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267014/best-approach-for-data-storage-in-custom-web-app

Comment: Your question was closed 3 times and you  were told 3 times it was off-topic  because it was too opinion-based.  Do you think that the downvotes and closed question would have told you the no matter how much you **want** to know the answer, there are some questions that are not acceptable on Stack Overflow (or other Stack Exchange sites)

Comment: If you got 3 answers to the question, they would likely be 3 different ones, so where would you be?  Opinion based questions are OT because they do not, by definition, result in an Answer.  Rather, several *possible* answers which may or may not apply given the *very* limited context you can provide in an SO post.  If there is a lot riding on the decision, maybe you should hire a consultant?  *We absorb uncertainty*

Comment: @psubsee2003, that's because it's some people's opinion. My questions wasn't opinion based, I was looking for an answer from users of MongoDB or NoSQL or DynamoDB, not "opinions" so that behaviour was unacceptable and I'll keep changing my question and keep asking until I get my answer from experienced people instead of experiencing

Comment: @Plutonix, I would never do that because it will be "a consultant". I don't want "a consultant" I want to learn experiences of users of several different product and I'll be able to decide which one was the best in defending their system and who was right about certain system/software

Comment: Opinion-based questions go on Reddit.

Comment: This sounds as if a usual forum would be a better place to ask questions like this.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung, now that's a great comment! Thank you!

Comment: @bummi, any example of such forum for my problem? I wasn't able to find a good one with enough amount of users

Comment: @user3404070 you don't really seem to understand.  You may have wanted"factual" answers from "experienced" users but a question about Best Practices is just an open invite for opinions.  That is why we don;t accept those types of questions - you can't control the answers.  It's not about want you want but it is about the types of answers.  When there is no 1 correct answer and only answers based on experiences, then it is not on-topic.

Comment: @psubsee2003, but I think for my problem, really only one system would work and when people who answer debate together and see each other's answer, finally everyone will sort of agree that one answer is the right one. If that's the case I can say EVERY single question is opinion based in SO, let's close them all! "How can I write data to file in PHP?" "Question closed, you can do that with 10 methods and it's opinion based, good bye and have a nice day"

Comment: @user3404070 you said it right in your comment.... **debate**.  Debate topics are not welcome.  that is why your questions were closed.

Comment: @psubsee2003, good. So I suggest you all to close ALL questions in SO, because, example: "How can I write data to file in PHP?" "Question closed, you can do that with 10 methods and it's opinion based, good bye and have a nice day" My problem is, I don't like "opinion" of people who think my question is "opinion-based", their "opinion" is wrong. That's all I'm saying

Comment: `finally everyone will sort of agree that one answer is the right one` that will be the day!

Comment: @Plutonix, indeed!

Comment: ACK.  Opening SO to opinions would be like inviting a pile of Arsenal and Spurs fans into one party with free beer and firearms.

Comment: It's funny, at the end of the day EVERYTHING Is opinion based. SO's rules are simply ignorant and lead anyone interpreting them anyway they want. This simply becomes "My opinion is that your opinion is worthless. But since I have power given to me by the gods, I will show you that your opinion is worthless because my opinion is not an opinion but from the lips of god".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got two thoughts on this.

First, the closures are correct; this is **entirely** opinion based.  There are lots of ways to solve this particular issue, as you note in your own question.  There's not enough subjective material here to go off of to even give you a constructive answer.

Second, you're doing a ton of early optimization here; you typically worry about load and capacity once you've actually got those problems.  If you're just starting out, then there's little reason to worry about performance unless a lot (~5,000 - 50,000) of users start hitting your website.

Comment: But I know I'll have optimization issues and possible huge amount of users, so why write lots of codes and classes for example based on MySQL, then run into issues and look for fix?

Comment: Once you have those problems, then you should fix them.  There's no sense in spending any time and effort on a problem that doesn't exist.  Once you're actually *at* that point (and from your question, you mention "possible" and "potential" and "future", so I don't believe you're there yet), then you can start looking for solutions that best fit your specific problem.  Usually, a software engineer will be willing to take those problems on.

Comment: Well, I have a different opinion..

Comment: @MartinJames, me too. I think writing so much code with MySQL and then running into problem is a disaster. Now changing everything to NosQL (let's say) and importing all existing data etc. will be a pain! What about users? They can't wait for me to fix stuff for several hours maybe days!

Comment: Again - you're worrying about a problem that doesn't exist yet.  You haven't done any tests to determine exactly where the pain point is.  Once you do those tests, then (and only then) should you look to optimize.  I'll only say it once more: there's no sense in spending any time trying to solve the optimization problems. [Recall the first rule of optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes):  don't do it.

Answer (score 7):

First and foremost, since you kept trying 4 times, apparently someone needs to hit you over the head with a [2x4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumber#Dimensional_lumber) to make you understand that there are some types of questions that are off-topic regardless of what you **want**.

The idea of seeking *best practices* are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  You can say that you want factual answers based on experience all you want, but that is not want you will get.... you will get an answer from anyone and everyone who has an opinion on the topic.  And since there is no "one" right answer, you will get assorted answers with conflicting opinions on what is right.

While many who participate in these sites would love to survey the opinions of the experts that are members with the hope that a good idea will eventually come out of the discussion, the simple fact is questions of this type are not welcome on virtually all Stack Exchange sites.  The format of Stack Exchange just does not deal well with these types of debatable issues. They becomes too noisy and too argumentative and distract from the **questions** and **answers** part of the site.  There are other places on the internet that welcomes these types of questions.